# Wifi P2P data sharing from server to client

Tags: android, wifip2p

I am using [this demo]https://github.com/akshay-ap/WifiP2P to connect devices throw WIFI,
but in this demo , client is send message to server. but I want to send message from server to multiple client. I have researched so many things, but can't get succeeded.
If anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: So you have 2 devices that are interconnected to each other via Wifi and you want to transfer data between them, between an app and a Wifi device. Am i getting it right?

Comment: @SagarBalyan yes

Comment: did you by any chance found something to achieve that ? :/